# Unable to change DocBlock comments color in VSCode for PHP

Tags: php, editor, visual-studio-code

I have looked all over the place but with no luck. The DocBlock comments in my VS Code theme are in 3 different colors (see screenshot). I would like it all to be in gray (just 1 color). I realize this depends on the theme itself (I am using `Atom One Dark`). How could I change it so that the comment text would be in one color (gray)?

I was able to change the DockBlock comments for javascript with this setting but it only worked for `javascript` but not for `PHP`.

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "name": "storage.type.class.jsdoc",
                "scope":
                "storage.type.class.jsdoc,entity.name.type.instance.jsdoc,variable.other.jsdoc",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#5c6370"
                }
            }
        ],
    },
```

This also didn't work

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "comments": "#5c6370",
    },
```

**Screenshot** (as you see my comments are in 3 colors - gray, purpule and yellow)

[image: Image of Yaktocat]

Comment: find the TextMate scope of the wrongly colored part and add it to the customization, php uses other scopes than javascript

Comment: @rioV8 how do I do that, I'm not sure.. ?

Comment: use command `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @rioV8 I was able to achive exactly what I wanted. So I will share my `settings.json` if anyone else is looking for a solution to this.

I also learned that you can select multiple scopes by separating them with a space. But the order is important and it looks like needs to be in reverse order from what the inspect editor shows. Go figure..

Here is my `settings.json` *(for javascript and PHP comments)*

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "storage.type.class.jsdoc,entity.name.type.instance.jsdoc,variable.other.jsdoc",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#485c6c"
                }
            },

            {
                "scope": "storage.type.class.jsdoc punctuation.definition.block.tag.jsdoc",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#485c6c"
                }
            },

            {
                "scope": "comment.block.documentation.phpdoc.php",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#5c6370"
                }
            },

            {
                "scope": "keyword.other.phpdoc.php,comment.block.documentation.phpdoc.php",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#76687d"
                }
            },

            {
                "scope": "keyword.other.type.php,meta.other.type.phpdoc.php,comment.block.documentation.phpdoc.php",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#76687d"
                }
            },

            {
                "scope": "support.class.php",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#E5C07B"
                }
            },

            {
                "scope": "meta.other.type.phpdoc.php,comment.block.documentation.phpdoc.php",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#5c6370"
                }
            },

            {
                "scope": "meta.other.type.phpdoc.php support.class.php",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#5c6370"
                }
            },
            
            {
                "scope": "meta.other.type.phpdoc.php support.class.builtin.php",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#5c6370"
                }
            },
        ],
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on @martin-zeltin's answer, the scopes that are required for comments and docblocks are only these and also require the inclusion of the `comments` notation:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": "#187c35", // Comment text colour
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            // Comment punctuation (eg //)
            "scope": "punctuation.definition.comment",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#2dc672"
            }
        },
        {
            // Descriptor item (eg @param, @return)
            "scope": "keyword.other.phpdoc.php,comment.block.documentation.phpdoc.php",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#2dc672"
            }
        },
        {
            // Regular inner docblock text
            "scope": "meta.other.type.phpdoc.php,comment.block.documentation.phpdoc.php",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#187c35"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

End result:

[image]